# Sinatra, progress bar in upload form

Tags: ruby, iframe, file-upload, sinatra, mongrel

I'm developing a Sinatra app that consists of an upload form, with a progress bar indicating how much of the upload has completed.
The process, as described by [ryan dahl](http://four.livejournal.com/730831.html), is the following:

> HTTP upload  progress  bars are rather obfuscated- they typically involve a process running on the server keeping track of the size of the tempfile that the HTTP server is writing to, then on the client side an AJAX call is made every couple seconds to the server during the upload to ask for the progress of the upload.

Every upload has a random `session-id`, and to keep track of the association i employ a `class variable` in my app (i know, that's horrible -- if you've got better ideas, please tell me)

```
configure do
  @@assoc = {}
end
```

I have a `POST` route for the upload, and a `GET` one for the AJAX polling.
Inside the `POST` route i save the association of `session-id`, `Tempfile`, and total size.

```
post '/files' do
  tmp = params[:file][:tempfile]
  # from here on, @@assoc[@sid] should have a value, even in other routes
  @@assoc[@sid] = { :file => tmp, :size => env['CONTENT_LENGTH'] } 
  File.open("#{options.filesdir}/#{filename}", 'w+') do |file|
    file << tmp.read
  end
end
```

In the `GET` route, i calculate the percentage based on the `Tempfile`'s current size:

```
get '/status/:sid' do
  h = @@assoc[params[:sid]]
  unless h.nil?
    percentage = (h[:file].size / h[:size].to_f) * 100 
    "#{percentage}%"
  else
    "0%"
  end 
end
```

The problem is that until the `POST` request hasn't completed (i.e., after it has read all of the `Tempfile`) the `h.nil?` returns `true`, which doesn't really make sense as I've just assigned `@@assoc[@sid]` a value in the other route.

So, what am I missing here?

**EDIT:** I've tried

- `set :reload, false`
- `set :environment, :production`
- `config { @@assoc ||= {} }`
- **I also tried throwing a relational db at it (SQLite with DataMapper)**

Neither worked.

Comment: The `@@assoc[@sid] = {...` line is missing a `}` at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think i got what the problem is:

`tmp = params[:file][:tempfile]` doesn't return until the file has been fully received.

Answer (score 1):

```
@@assoc[@sid] = { :file => tmp, :size => env['CONTENT_LENGTH'] }
```

should be

```
@@assoc[params[:sid]] = { :file => tmp, :size => env['CONTENT_LENGTH'] }
```

Comment: yeah, it's a typo in the question, it's ok in the real app.
thanks anyway for reporting.